# Change default homepage for Roo generated app using SpringMVC

Tags: spring, default, spring-roo

By default when the web app starts it starts with the home page generated by roo with view name as "index"

Suppose i add new custom controller using following command,

```
web mvc controller ~.web.ViewHomeController --preferredMapping /homepage1
```

It generates the following code,

```
@RequestMapping("/homepage1/**")
@Controller

public class ViewHomeController {
   @RequestMapping
   public void get(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request, 
                                  HttpServletResponse response) {
   }

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "{id}")
   public void post(@PathVariable Long id, ModelMap modelMap, 
                 HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   }

   @RequestMapping
   public String index() {
     return "home/homepage1";
   }
}
```

I want the "home/homepage1" page to be the default page to be shown when the Roo Application starts.

Can i please get some guidance/details on changes i need to make to enable "home/homepage1" as default homepage for my application.

Thanks for help in advance. I am using latest version of Spring ROO, 1.1.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your webmvc-config.xml, replace the following section:

```
<!-- selects a static view for rendering without the need for an explicit controller -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
```

with a view name you prefer.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response. That helped.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Kev!

Comment: Being new user don't yet have permissions yet to Vote Up. But i did mark mark the answer as accepted. thanks.

Comment: You have right to upvote from day 0, just click on the arrow pointing upwards next to the question.